# How to add a new key/value to an object inside an array in mongodb document using python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "61407" },
  "name": [
    { "name": "belarusian" }
  ]
}
```

I need to add an element `region` inside name array so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "61407" },
  "name": [
    { "name": "belarusian", "region": "Belarus" }
  ]
}
```

I tried using:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    db1.cuisines.update_one(
        {'_id': ObjectId(df['_id'][i])},
        { "$push": { 
            "name": { "region": df['name.region'][i] }
        }}
    )
```

but the output I got is:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "61407" },
  "name": [
    { "name": "belarusian" },
    { "region": "Belarus"  }
  ]
}
```

Both `name` and `region` should be inside a single object rather than separate objects.

Comment: You can use the Array Update Operators - for modifying a specific array element: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/update/#array . `$push` just adds a new element to the array - thats not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `region` for all array elements, you need to use `$[]` ([manual link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---)).

As you use only `id` in your find portion, all array elements in that document will be selected. So you probably want to use `$[]` to update them all:

```
db1.cuisines.update_one(
    { '_id': ObjectId(df['_id'][i]) },
    { "$set": {
        "name.$[].region": df['name.region'][i]
    }}
)
```

If you want to add `region` to one element with a particular name in the array, you need to use `$`, which modifies the first matching element only ([manual link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/?_ga=1.12567092.1864968360.1429722620#up._S_)):

```
db1.cuisines.update_one(
    { '_id': ObjectId(df['_id'][I]), 'name.name': 'someName' },
    { "$set": {
        "name.$.region": df['name.region'][i]
    }}
)
```